# Adding Extra weight to order total

Tags: ubercart

Am working on an ecommerce site and am using ubercart module for that. Now am stuck with an issue which is ' if the weight of order total is >=1kg, i want to add an extra 150g to the order total and final amount calculated should include this extra grams aaded. for example if i have an order for a product worth 1kg, in the checkout page the final weight of order is 1.150 kg. but the product weight should not be increased.only the final order has an extra weight added. can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Using code we can calculate total weight using product quantity and weight from uc order. Then its possible to add additional weight according to your conditions and pass the calculated total weight according to your need.

Comment: @aby... Issue solved..??